# What does it mean in the output log in scip?

Tags: scip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6q2k.png)

What does it mean in the output log in scip? Why some lines output node 1?

By using the command `display display`, I have already known the meaning of the parameters but I didn't know why is the node parameter 1 on the first few lines.

Answer (score 0):

You get a lot of lines at the root node, since a new line is printed

a) every time a heuristic finds a new incumbent (new best solution)
b) cuts are added, improving the dual bound